# subprocess.check_output() not providing full iwconfig output

Tags: python, subprocess, iwconfig

I am trying to make a python program to display information about the WiFi connection, but I have hit a snag. subprocess.check_output() is not working the way I need it to.

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>test = subprocess.check_output("iwconfig")
```

Provides me with the following:
    enp9s0    no wireless extensions.

```
virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

But when I go into a terminal and do the same command, it provides me with this:

```
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:[Network Name]  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: [access point] 
      Bit Rate=81 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:26   Missed beacon:0

enp9s0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this (my goal is to get all of the information that I get when I run it in the terminal when I use python to run it). I tried looking at the docs, but I do not understand everything said there. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I cannot replicate where are you running the code?

Comment: I was running it on python 3.4 through KDE Konsole on fedora 22 workstation.

Comment: works fine for me on ubuntu from pretty much everywhere, must be specific to kde.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why.

Comment: I just went onto gnome and tried both sets of code (the one without stderr and the one with it) on both Konsole and the Gnome terminal and got the same result as I got on KDE. It must be something with fedora.

Comment: The only thing that changed for me was the order of some lines using  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, perhaps a different version of iwconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the output may be going to stderr.

```
test = subprocess.check_output("iwconfig", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!