# subprocess.check_output does not return full output with oping

Tags: python, subprocess

I already checked: [subprocess.check_output() not providing full iwconfig output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268359/subprocess-check-output-not-providing-full-iwconfig-output) sadly same result.

Basically this works:
subprocess.check_output(["oping", "-c", "5", "1.1.1.1"])
But as soon I try to tell oping to ping multiple ip's at once, it only give me a shorted output.

Like this: subprocess.check_output(["oping", "-c", "5", "1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9"])

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `oping`, but it probably wants multiple IP addresses as separate parameters, rather than a single parameter with embedded spaces.  How would you type a multiple address command at the command line?

Comment: @jasonharper Just oping -c 5 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be correct what @jasonharper said.
You need to pass them as individual parameters

> e.g ["oping", "-c", "8","1.1.1.1","8.8.8.8"]